# Batch Send Email via FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, massemailmessage

I am new to this so any help is much appreciated.

We are trying to leverage exacttarget in place of an existing email system like cheetahmail.  Does exacttarget provide an API to place a file containing lets say a 100 rows, where each row contains the name, email, some text content(to be shown on the email), and the email to be sent to.

So in effect a bulk send email capability where the content and template are in-line per row, where each row basically will need to be sent as a separate email.

Comment: So basically, Is there an API Provided basically to send batch/bulk emails mentioned in the flat file. The Job Send (Mass Email) sends the same content to a list of recipients, but my requirement is to send different content to every email via batch.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? Maybe two or three lines?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.  You will need to build one email using dynamic content that sends to a data extension.  It is a very advanced and sophisticated solution that is going to require quite a bit of study on your end at help.exacttarget.com.  You may even decide you want to purchase a services engagement to help you with this.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Timothy, When u say One Email - What does this mean, where would i create this ?

Comment: You would need to go into the email section of the application, then go under Content-> Emails and create a new one.  You will probably want to choose HTML paste.